# editing xml using C#

Tags: c#, xml, xml-parsing

I have that xml document :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>

<reminders>
  <reminder>
    <Title>Alarm1</Title>
    <Description>Desc1</Description>
    <Time>03/07/2012 10:11AM</Time>
    <snooze>1</snooze>
    <repeat>None</repeat>
  </reminder>
  <reminder>
    <Title>Alarm2</Title>
    <Description>Desc2</Description>
    <Time>03/07/2012 10:11AM</Time>
    <snooze>15</snooze>
    <repeat>Daily</repeat>
  </reminder>
</reminders>
```

And say i would like to create a full reminder child like :

```
  <reminder>
    <Title>NEW-Alarm</Title>
    <Description>New-Desc</Description>
    <Time>03/07/2012 10:11AM</Time>
    <snooze>15</snooze>
    <repeat>Daily</repeat>
  </reminder>
```

How can i do that in C# ?

And also i`d like to edit some child like from :

```
<Title>NEW-Alarm</Title>
```

to be

```
<Title>Modified-NEW-Alarm</Title>
```

I am fresh to XML and i really did my best , actually i am opening like 13 webpages for xml but none of them has what i really need, so i`ll truly appreciate your help.

Comment: -1 - "opening like 13 webpages" does not yet show any sample code that you tried and have problems with.

Comment: I tried lots of code samples and none worked.

Comment: Well then, you didn't open enough web pages.

Comment: Normally it is interesting why down votes, but I'm really interested why +1. @R.Vector, "none worked" is hard to help with - it is extremely rare that samples will do **exactly** what you want. SO is to help with concrete problems - show one and effort to solve and you get concrete useful answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Load the doc with [XDocument class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument.aspx)

Add a element (edit PATH with your data) :

```
XElement newEl = new XElement(new XElement("reminder",
                                new XElement("Title", "NEW-Alarm"),
                                new XElement("Description", "New-Desc"),
                                new XElement("Time", "03/07/2012 10:11AM"),
                                new XElement("snooze", "15"),
                                new XElement("repeat", "Daily")));
                    doc.Root.Add(newEl);
                    doc.Save(PATH);
```

To change, we must first find the element (with LINQ) and then apply the SetValue method.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xelement.setvalue.aspx

Comment: Thank you for your answer , but i got an error :
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
on  doc.Root.Add(newEl);

Comment: You must load your document. See XDocument.Load() method

Answer (score 4):

I would take a look at using XDocument. You may want to search the web for examples of creating XML with it but this answer from the unstoppable Jon Skeet is a good place to start:

[XML file creation using XDocument in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2948255/xml-file-creation-using-xdocument-in-c-sharp)

Hope that helps.

Also see these links:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/169598/Parse-XML-Documents-by-XMLDocument-and-XDocument

http://www.leghumped.com/blog/2009/06/30/c-xml-with-xdocuments/

http://forums.asp.net/t/1736899.aspx/1?Help+using+XDocument+in+LINQ+with+ASP+Net+C+

Answer (score 1):

You need to look into the [XDocument](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument.aspx) as a way to open your XML Document and then take a look at the documentation for [XElement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xelement.aspx) to see how easy it is to build nodes.

Each documentation page has great samples.