# XDocument Implementation

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-xml

I'm trying to best understand how to implement the following XML as an XDocument, but I'm rather new to the XDocument stuff and I'm running into a conceptual problem of how to get around the multi-attribute in an Element with a value nested inside another Element.

The below is a sample of the XML -- any help would be appreciated

```
<LVNPImport xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <InterfaceIdentifier>835</InterfaceIdentifier>
    <FolderPaths>
        <Folder fromDate="" toDate="" contactName="APerson" email="AnEmail">Remittance Advice</Folder>
        <Folder>%FACILITY%</Folder>
        <Folder>%PAYORID%</Folder>
        <Folder>%REMITDATE YYYY%</Folder>
        <Folder>%REMITDATE MMMM YYYY%</Folder>
    </FolderPaths>
    <DocumentType>RA</DocumentType>
    <DocumentDescription>%REMITDATE MM-DD-YY%</DocumentDescription>
    <TotalFiles>1</TotalFiles>
</LVNPImport>
```

*EDIT*

The above is a template -- I'm not reading in, I'm writing out so I need to create the above  as an XDoc.

I'm just getting into the XDocument stuff and what I have is pretty much what you can find with most examples on Stack.

Comment: What is your exact problem? You can load the XML into an XDocument object and you can then query the structure and the XElement attributes...

Comment: Show us what you've tried, so we can help you solve your actual problem, not just give solution.

Comment: @ReinderWit

The above is a template -- I'm trying to figure out how to create the above as an XDocument.

Comment: OK, do you have some code you've already tried out? The implementation shouldn't be to hard...

Comment: I'm sure we can help, but we need to know more about where your problem is. Are you trying to get the values of these attributes starting with the `XDocument`? Can you post the code as well as the XML

Comment: @ReinderWit

[Pretty much I'm following the ideas presented in the following answer posted on another question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2948356/1693074)

Comment: @ChrisBallard See my answer to ReinderWit -- what I'm trying to get past, conceptually, is how I can add an element that has multiple attributes with a value which is nested inside another element. The area in the XML is everything in the <Folder> element

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pass multiple attributes inside the `new XElement` overload, as the objects content:

```
XElement folderPath = new XElement("FolderPaths");
folderPath.Add(
    new XElement(
        "Folder", 
        new XAttribute("fromDate", String.Empty), 
        new XAttribute("toDate", String.Empty), 
        new XAttribute("contactName", "APerson"), 
        new XAttribute("email", "AnEmail"), 
        "Remittance Advice"
    )
);
```

Comment: This was extremely helpful, I've voted up your post -- thank you!

Answer (score 1):

For anyone looking at this, between the help I've gotten on this answer from @ReinderWit as well as the answer from another question (see the other comments in the question) I was able to figure out how to build up the XDocument.

The code follows:

```
            _folderviewContents =
            new XDocument(
                new XElement("InterfaceIdentifier", "835"),
                //Start of FolderPaths 
                new XElement("FolderPaths",
                    new XElement("Folder",
                        new XAttribute("fromDate", String.Empty),
                        //attributes for Folder w/ lots of attributes
                        new XAttribute("toDate", String.Empty),
                        new XAttribute("contactName", "APerson"),
                        new XAttribute("email", "AnEmail"),
                        //value for that long Folder w/ lots of attributes
                        "Remittance Advice"),
            //Facility
                    new XElement("Folder", String.Empty),
            //PayorID
                    new XElement("Folder", String.Empty),
            //RemitDate Year
                    new XElement("Folder", String.Empty),
            //RemitDate Month/Year
                    new XElement("Folder", String.Empty)),
            new XElement("DocumentType", "RA"),
            new XElement("DocumentDescription",String.Empty),
            new XElement("TotalFiles", "1"));
```

I still need to add the XML version and the Namespace, but those seem simple enough to do. Hopefully this helps others in the future with building XDocs that are a bit weird and not-so-straightforward.