# How to write xsd:schema tag using XmlDocument

Tags: c#, xml, xsd

I'm trying to write a XML-document programatically.

I need to add `<xsd:schema>` tag to my document.

Currently I have:

```
var xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();

var root = xmlDoc.CreateElement("root");
xmlDoc.AppendChild(root);

var xsdSchemaElement = xmlDoc.CreateElement("schema");
xsdSchemaElement.Prefix = "xsd";
xsdSchemaElement.SetAttribute("id", "root");

root.AppendChild(xsdSchemaElement);
```

However, this renders to:

```
<root>
  <schema id="root" />
</root>
```

How do I get the tag to be `<xsd:schema>`?

Already tried `var xsdSchemaElement = xmlDoc.CreateElement("xsd:schema");` which simply ignores the `xsd:`.

**Edit #1**

Added method

```
private static XmlSchema GetTheSchema(XmlDocument xmlDoc)
{
    var schema = new XmlSchema();
    schema.TargetNamespace = "xsd";
    return schema;
}
```

which is called like `xmlDoc.Schemas.Add(GetTheSchema(xmlDoc));` but does not generate anything in my target `XML`.

Comment: The XmlDocument has a Property called Schemas. Have you tried adding your schema definition there?

Comment: Using `xmlDoc.Schemas.Add(GetMySchema(xmlDoc))` is not throwing any exceptions, but also not writing any xml to my target-file. Any good tutorials on how to use `XmlSchema` you know about?

Comment: @KingKerosin are you able to use LINQ-to-XML instead of `XmlDocument`?

Comment: @har07 Yes. Just read that starting with `XDocument` is way better than `XmlDocument`. Any good tutorials on that?

Comment: @KingKerosin I don't have any specific tutorials to recommend. Here are some examples that you may learn from : [MSDN: XDocument Class Overview](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387063.aspx), [XML file creation Using XDocument in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2948255/xml-file-creation-using-xdocument-in-c-sharp)

Answer (score 0):

Using LINQ-to-XML, you can nest `XElement`s and `XAttributes`s in a certain hierarchy to construct an XML document. As for namespace prefix, you can use `XNamespace`.

Notice that every namespace prefix, such as `xsd` in your case, has to be declared before it is used, something like `xmlns:xsd = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"`.

```
XNamespace xsd = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema";
var doc = 
    new XDocument(
        //root element 
        new XElement("root",
            //namespace prefix declaration
            new XAttribute(XNamespace.Xmlns+"xsd", xsd.ToString()),
            //child element xsd:schema
            new XElement(xsd + "schema",
                //attribute id
                new XAttribute("id", "root"))));
Console.WriteLine(doc.ToString());
```

**output :**

```
<root xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xsd:schema id="root" />
</root>
```